# Erro - Select com SUM

Tags: mysql

Caros;

Tenho uma tabela com diversas informações, dentre elas um campo com valor_boleto e outro com vencimento.

Precisava que primeiro fosse ordenado o compo vencimento com o mes atual (corrente) e depois que ordenado, somasse os valores de valor_boleto.

Tentei a query abaixo, porem sem sucesso:

```
SELECT * FROM boleto WHERE extract(year_month from vencimento) = 201805, (SUM(-valor_boleto)+5000) AS valor_boleto FROM boleto";
```

O erro gerado é de sintaxe a partir do SUM.

Se eu executo apenas a ordenação do mes corrente, funciona corretamente:

```
SELECT * FROM boleto WHERE extract(year_month from vencimento) = 201805;
```

Onde estou errando, ou melhor tem uma frma mais simples de efetuar esta consulta?

Comment: Amigo, apesar de alguns erros no seu sql, acho que entendi o que você está querendo. Mas vamos definir algumas coisas antes. Você precisa selecionar todas as colunas de sua tabela ou queres apenas a soma dos valores agrupados pelo período?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, se entendi bem o que deseja, creio que agrupando pelo periodo você consiga a somatória dos valores dos boletos como deseja, segue o código:

```
SELECT (SUM(valor_boleto)+5000) as soma, extract(year_month from vencimento) as periodo FROM boleto 
GROUP BY extract(year_month from vencimento);
```

segue o exemplo: [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f984df/2)

Comment: Boa noite @inacio. Quase isso meu amigo, retornou a soma de todos os meses. Como faço para setar o mês atual. Tentei setar na mão   extract(year_month from vencimento) = '201805' e o vencimento veio todo vazio, apenas a soma retornou resultado.

Comment: Amigo, resolvi. Tinha que setar no final do codigo o mes que eu quero. Vou dar como resposta aceita. Abraços.